# Where do I post an opening for a freelance AWS Consultant?

Tags: support

I'm looking to hire a freelance AWS consultant to help get me setup on EC2, EBS, RDS, etc. Where would I post this?

I'm assuming it's not in the general SF or SO question feeds.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6):

The [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) website is as close as we've got. There really isn't anything aimed at short-term work.

Answer (score 6):

It might also be worth mentioning in [The Comms Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) (ServerFault's chat room). Many of the regulars do moonlight, and you wouldn't be the first to use the room to find someone to do contract work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also click the tag and view the top users for that particular term within the past 30 days.  They sometimes include contact info in their profile.  I sometimes use this method to find specialists.

For a good example, check out my [profile page.](https://serverfault.com/users/30996/jamieb)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest elance.com or odesk.com for short term work/projects

Comment: I'm not sure why yo got downvoted. eLance has some decent contractors there, often guys like many ServerFaulters that have jobs, but also do side work for spare change. You have to pick through the extremely low-wage / low-talent pool, but there are gems there. It's a decent place to find quick spot-work as a contractor and also get contractors without having to use a recruiter or nag friends. (Disclaimer: I have an eLance profile).

Comment: (But yes, the original question was more specifically looking for StackExchange resources to find work, so perhaps this answer of yours would be better as a comment.)

Comment: I didn't see where the question was specific to SE, but I assume you are correct.